# Why is my answer to this cube measurement problem correct when it doesn't match the real answer?

Tags: volume, cubics

While doing a newspaper problem section yesterday, I came upon the following question.

> A box has a length four times its height, which is a third of its width. If its volume is 768 cubic centimetres, what is the width of the box?

Naturally, I set about it as follows:

$$lhw=768$$
$$l=4h=\frac{w}{3}$$

From this follows:

$$3l=12h=w$$
$$h*4h*12h=768$$

Now,
$$12h*4h*h=48h^2*h=48h^3=768$$

From this,
$$\frac{768}{48}=h^3=16$$
$$\sqrt[3]{16}=2.51984209979=h$$

If 
Inserting this into the problem yields:
$$(h)2.51984209979*(4h)10.07936839916*(12h)30.23810519748=768.00000000024$$

So, it seems as if my solution is nearly optimal, with

$$w=12h=30.23810519748$$

Yet, the solution given in the newspaper is $w=12$. From a naive perspective, this seems ludicrous.

If
$$w=12$$
$$3l=12h=w$$
Then
$$l=4, h=1$$
But
$$12*4*1\neq768$$

Where is my error? Is there any way to derive $w=12$ from the starting problem?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is an ambiguity. Is W/3=L or H? Evidently the newspaper assumes $768=12\times4\times16$. So $L=16,H=4,W=12$. It looks as though they meant that H =W/3.

Comment: I am an idiot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you got "$h \cdot 4h \cdot 12h = 768$" from.

The correct deductions from what you're given are
$l = 4h$ and $h = \frac 13 w$, and hence $l = \frac 43 w$. Now $lwh = \frac 49 w^3 = 768$, and it follows that $w = \sqrt[3]{1728} = 12$.

Comment: I assumed it followed from "$l=4h$", "$w=12h$" and "$lwh=768$" that "$h*4h*12h=768$".